# Powershell - Using TSSession is giving mixed results

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to use Get-TSSession to check for disconnected sessions, but am having issues.
I use Get-ADComputer to pull my list of servers, and while Get-ADComputer works exactly how I want it, when I use Get-TSSession with it, it's pulling only my domain controllers for some reason and i'm not sure why.

For Example here is the whole script i'm attempting to run, but like I said it only pulls 4 domain controller servers and that's it.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module PSTerminalServices
$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*server*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
{ 
Get-TSSession -ComputerName $Server
}
```

Now if I run this same command but by itself it gives me dozens of servers back.

```
Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*server*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you know if you have access to run `Get-TSSession` against any servers other than your DCs? Are you using a Domain Admin account or something? Are you able to run the command against one of the other servers if you do it manually?

Comment: Yes I able to do anything I need to, as I have a domain admin account. I have tried it with specific servers by name instead of pulling from AD and it works like a charm. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I would suggest trying verbose logging. Try `ForEach ($Server in $Servers) { Get-TSSession -ComputerName $Server -Verbose }` and see if that sheds some light on things.

Comment: Thank you @TheMadTechnician, unfortunately that didn't really help. It just shows the connection process  to the domain controllers. It never even attempts to hit the other servers.

Comment: That strongly implies that you only have the domain controllers in `$Servers`. Can you echo what is in `$Servers` before you hit your `ForEach` loop? Are you running the script differently than how you run the individual commands?

Comment: Are you invoking this command remotely? Could be double hop if so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Import-Module PSTerminalServices
$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*server*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
ForEach ($Server in $Servers)
{ 
    Write-Output $Server
    Try {
        Get-TSSession -ComputerName $Server
    }
    Catch {
        Write-Output "An error occurred while enumerating $server"
    }
}
```

Your code also stopped after enumerating domain controllers until I augmented the code to the above.

Comment: I don’t see any augmentation. What exactly did you change?

Comment: Darrell, I did this as well, with the try and catch, while also filtering out domain controllers and I had deleted an old decommissioned server, and that seem to do the trick.